# Spring Boot: Log all incoming HTTP requests when using an embedded Jetty server?

Tags: spring-mvc, jetty, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I'm building a web app using Spring Boot 1.1.5.RELEASE and I've configured an embedded Jetty as described [in the related Spring Boot's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat).

I want to **log all incoming HTTP requests** and the only solution I can think (after reading ["how to configure Jetty"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-jetty) in Spring Boot's docs) is to introduce an EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer:

```
package com.acme.rest;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


/**
 * blah blah
 * 
 * @author Dimi
 */
@Component
public class EmbededJettyConfig implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer # customize
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(final ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        // checks whether the container is Jetty
        if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            ((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                    .addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {

        return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * 
             * @see org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer #
             * customize
             */
            @Override
            public void customize(final Server server) {

                HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
                RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
                handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {new DefaultHandler(), requestLogHandler});
                server.setHandler(handlers);

                NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog("logs/requests.log");
                requestLog.setExtended(false);
                requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The application now fails to start throwing an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to
>   configure default servlet handling

In short: what is the correct way of configuring the embedded Jetty's logging in Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring provides a filter that can log the requests just add a [`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html) to your configuration, works regardless of your container and you don't have to mess around with customizer. If you want the NCSA format you might reimplement the method that generates the message to log.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, that helped a lot. I ended up extending an AbstractRequestLoggingFilter which provides exactly the callbacks I am interested in. I'll accept your comment if you convert it into an aswer.

Comment: Do not make RequestLogHandler a standalone handler, it needs to wrap your main Handler chain.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt sorry, I don't fully get what you're saying..can you please provide some more context?

Answer (score 5):

Jetty 9.3.8 has a new method `setRequestLog` on the server.

```
@Component
public class EnableRequestLog implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    private static final JettyServerCustomizer USE_SLF4J_REQUEST_LOG =
            server -> server.setRequestLog(new Slf4jRequestLog());

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            ((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                    .addServerCustomizers(USE_SLF4J_REQUEST_LOG);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Expected a Jetty container factory but encountered " + container.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of Jetty's Slf4jRequestLog you can implement a specific `RequestLog`. See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html

Answer (score 1):

Coming a bit late, but I experienced the same problem and the solution was to wrap the ServletHandler already created by boot in the RequestLogHandler like this:

```
@Component
public class EmbededJettyConfig implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer # customize
 */
@Override
public void customize(final ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    // checks whether the container is Jetty
    if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
        ((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                .addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
    }
}

@Bean
public JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {

    return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer #
         * customize
         */
        @Override
        public void customize(final Server server) {
            NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog("logs/requests.log");
            requestLog.setExtended(false);

            RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
            requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
            requestLogHandler.setHandler(server.getHandler());
            server.setHandler(requestLogHandler);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work with Spring Boot version 1.1.9 because JettyEmbeddedServletContainer handlers only JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext (a handler) or HandlerWrapper. I think there is no way to set multiple handler to embedded Jetty in Spring Boot because of this.

Code snippet from org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jettyJettyEmbeddedServletContainer.

```
@Override
public void start() throws EmbeddedServletContainerException {
    this.server.setConnectors(this.connectors);

    if (!this.autoStart) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        this.server.start();
        for (Handler handler : this.server.getHandlers()) {
            handleDeferredInitialize(handler);
        }
        Connector[] connectors = this.server.getConnectors();
        for (Connector connector : connectors) {
            connector.start();
            this.logger.info("Jetty started on port: " + getLocalPort(connector));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new EmbeddedServletContainerException(
                "Unable to start embedded Jetty servlet container", ex);
    }
}

private void handleDeferredInitialize(Handler handler) throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext) {
        ((JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext) handler).deferredInitialize();
    }
    else if (handler instanceof HandlerWrapper) {
        handleDeferredInitialize(((HandlerWrapper) handler).getHandler());
    }
}
```